# Put text right to switch in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have some switch and I need to put text right to the switch. I use Xamarin.Forms and I build interface with XAML.

What I have:     [what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teFKb.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a horizontal layout

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Switch/>
  <Label Text="This is my label"/>
</StackLayout>
```